# Создание материала в скрипте по имени шейдера

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо **через скрипт** создать материал с именем шейдера
"Legacy Shaders/Transparent/Bumped Diffuse",
то есть чтобы в редакторе он имел вид как на фото и на него назначить спрайт и карту нормалей. Как это можно сделать?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Материал создаётся с помощью конструкции ([shaderName] замените на имя вашего шейдера):

```
Material mat = new Material(Shader.Find("[shaderName]"));
```

Установка текстур в него происходит через метод `.SetTexture`, где в качестве строкового параметра идёт строковое имя соответствующего поля шейдера. [Пример из документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTexture.html):

```
    //Make sure to enable the Keywords
    m_Renderer.material.EnableKeyword ("_NORMALMAP");
    m_Renderer.material.EnableKeyword ("_METALLICGLOSSMAP");

    //Set the Texture you assign in the Inspector as the main texture (Or Albedo)
    m_Renderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", m_MainTexture);
    //Set the Normal map using the Texture you assign in the Inspector
    m_Renderer.material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", m_Normal);
    //Set the Metallic Texture as a Texture you assign in the Inspector
    m_Renderer.material.SetTexture ("_MetallicGlossMap", m_Metal);
```